# Unexpected [call] function behavior (in console using Chrome) in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

**So this is my code:**

```
function A(){
  var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
  console.log('before unshift: ', args);
  args.unshift(3);
  console.log('after unshift:', args);
}
```

**Now, when I call it:**

```
A(1, 2, 3)
```

**the result in the console is:**

> before unshift:  [3, 1, 2, 3]
>   after unshift: [3, 1, 2, 3]

**"before unshift" should be [1,2,3] though...?**

...Anyone know why?

---------- **USING: Chrome's Developer Tools**  ----------

Comment: Its because console has quirks. Try it with alert and see if you get the expected results.

Comment: Yep, it works exactly as expected in my Firefox+Firebug console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The console, at least in WebKit's Web Inspector, outputs "live" views of arrays, not snapshots of them at the time the log happened.

To get one of those, do

```
console.log('before unshift: ', args.slice());
```

For the case of objects (which presumably subsumes arrays), this is [WebKit bug #35801](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=35801).

Comment: hmm.. that's interesting. I would never have thought of that.. Just wondering, how did you get to that conclusion/info?

Comment: Experience. There's a WebKit bug for it, which I've referenced in a previous answer to a similar question... I'm digging through my old answers trying to find it now.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's a bug. The following is more obvious.

```
    var a = {b:1};
     console.log(a);
     a.b=2;
```

The result in the log is {b:2}. where it should be {b:1}.

Arrays are objects,too. So it also makes the mistake.

But the primitive value types don't encouter this bug.

Hope it helps.

Comment: I don't believe "asynchronous" is really accurate to describe the behavior of `console.log`. I may be wrong, but from what I've seen it synchronously outputs to the console, despite having delayed evaluation of any objects output there.

Comment: I mean it act as asychronous. Take this as an example:

`var a=1;
console.log(a);
alert(a);`


The result is that alert is fired first, then the console.log get executed.

Comment: sorry, man. Maybe I'm wrong. console.log isn't asynchronous. You are right. It's a bug maybe.